# Navigate between main content components using react-router-dom within nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

In this case, there is an `App` component which has a `Header` component which renders one header if the user is logged in and one if not. There is also an `Access` component which renders either a `Landing` component if user is not logged in or `Dashboard` if the user is logged in. The user has access to all routes if logged in. How do I render components using `react-router-dom` if the user is on the `Dashboard` component? Currently, `LeftNav` should always be in view while the components in the `main-content` `className` toggle based on the route. Currently only the `LeftNav` and `MainContent` components work on `"/"`, if navigated to `/test` or `/test/new neither the` LeftNav`or`TestComponent`render, however the`Header`component is still rendering correctly. What am I doing wrong here or how is this toggling between`main-content` components achieved?

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import Access from "./Access";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Access} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default App;

////////////////////////////////

import Landing from "./Landing";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

class Access extends Component {
    renderContent() {
        switch (this.props.auth) {
            case null:
                return;
            case false:
                return (
                    <Landing />
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <Dashboard />
                );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Access;

////////////////////////////////

import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LeftNav from "./dashboard/LeftNav";
import MainContent from "./dashboard/MainContent";
import TestContent from "./dashboard/TestContent";
import TestContentNew from "./dashboard/TestContentNew";

class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="dashboard-wrapper" style={dashboardWrapper}>
                    <LeftNav />
                    <div className="main-content">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" component={MainContent} />
                            <Route path="/test" component={TestContent} />
                            <Route path="/test/new" component={TestContentNew} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The main `Route` in your application ***only ever*** matches and renders a route when it *exactly* matches "/", so when you navigate to another path it ceases to match.

## Solution

I don't see *where* you pass `auth` as a prop to `Access`, but since it handles authentication ***and*** renders your actual routes you can simply just render *it* instead of a `Route` in `App`. It will always be rendered by the router and display either the landing page or the dashboard.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import Access from "./Access";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Access />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```